# preferencesDataStore read data from common method

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi instead of reading data individually from preferencesDataStore I am trying for common method means pass key return data related to key but its not working..

```
suspend fun <T> getData(key: Preferences.Key<T>): Flow<String> {
        val value: Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data
            .map { preferences ->
                preferences[key] ?: ""
            }
        return value
    }
```

Comment: You are passing String Type in Flow, pass T instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
private fun <T> getData(key: Preferences.Key<T>) = dataStore.data.map {
        it[key]
    }
```

& call it like this:

```
        val key = stringPreferencesKey("username")
        val data = getData(key)
        GlobalScope.launch {
            data.collect {
                Log.d("Data-", it.toString())
            }
        }
```

Comment: @karteekthati You can mark the answer as accepted if it's working for you.